# Strip year, month and date as int from a datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to strip out part of a date (stored in my database table as a datetime field) in the form 'YYYYMMDD'. I would like the output to be an integer.

For example the datetime 2017-03-28 20:44:35.000 would convert to 20170328.

This is my attempt so far:

```
CAST(
            CAST(DATEPART(year,transcriptCreationDateUTC) AS varchar(4))
            + CAST(DATEPART(month,transcriptCreationDateUTC) AS varchar(4))
            + CAST(DATEPART(day,transcriptCreationDateUTC) AS varchar(4))
        AS int)
```

This is ugly to say the least, and also has the issue that it strips out leading zeros in the month and day fields, so for example 2017-03-28 20:44:35.000 converts to 2017328 not 20170328 as I would like.

There must be a better way, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) with style 112 (which is `YYYYMMDD` format):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),transcriptCreationDateUTC,112)
```

If you really need the result as an INT, wrap in a `CAST(... AS INT)`:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),transcriptCreationDateUTC,112) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Huh?  Just convert to a `date`:

```
select cast(transcriptCreationDateUTC as date)
```

If you want this as a string:

```
select format(transcriptCreationDateUTC, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

If you are using a pre-2012 version of SQL Server, you can do:

```
select convert(varchar(10), transcriptCreationDateUTC, 112)
```

If you want these as an integer (which is not obvious given that your query returns a string), just convert these to an integer:

```
select cast(format(transcriptCreationDateUTC, 'yyyyMMdd') as int)
```

Or, use this arithmetic:

```
select (year(transcriptCreationDateUTC) * 10000 + 
        month(transcriptCreationDateUTC) * 100 + 
        day(transcriptCreationDateUTC)
       ) as yyyymmdd
```

Comment: As an integer, CAST(CONVERT(char(8), transcriptCreationDateUTC, 112) AS int).

Comment: Using cast to convert to a date does not get the desired output, for example  2017-03-28 20:44:35.000 converts to 2017-03-28 not 20170328. I need the output to be an integer in that form, not a date.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that nails it!